# Laravel Backpack Permission seeding "role does not exist"

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-backpack, laravel-permission

I would like to ask about Seeding in Laravel BackPack Permission Manager,

I'm trying default Backpack Permission Manager configuration, and trying to seed it with dummy data.

Here is my Roles and Permission seeder method:

```php
    public function run()
    {
        // Reset cached roles and permissions
        app()[\Spatie\Permission\PermissionRegistrar::class]->forgetCachedPermissions();

        // create permissions
        Permission::create(['name' => 'view members']);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'add members']);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'edit members']);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'delete members']);

        Role::create(['name' => 'super-admin'])
            ->givePermissionTo(Permission::all());

        Role::create(['name' => 'admin'])
            ->givePermissionTo('add members');
    }
```

And here is my User seeder method:

```php
    public function run()
    {
        factory(User::class)->create([
            'name' => 'Arianna',
            'email' => 'arianna@example.com'
        ])->assignRole('super-admin');
    }
```

These Seeder is fine, but I realized that the Users CRUD interface doesn't show roles correctly

users roles shown as "-",

roles shown as -

[image]

and when I checked the database, model_has_roles shown App\User as model type

App\User model_type:

[image]

I'm sure model_type should be App\Models\BackpackUser , so I tried seeding again now with BackpackUser class

now I got different problem, BackpackUser don't have any roles, as roles needs to be in "backpack" guard to be assigned to BackpackUser

```
 Spatie\Permission\Exceptions\RoleDoesNotExist  : There is no role named `super-admin`.

  at .\vendor\spatie\laravel-permission\src\Exceptions\RoleDoesNotExist.php:11
     7| class RoleDoesNotExist extends InvalidArgumentException
     8| {
     9|     public static function named(string $roleName)
    10|     {
  > 11|         return new static("There is no role named `{$roleName}`.");
    12|     }
    13|
    14|     public static function withId(int $roleId)
    15|     {

  Exception trace:

  1   Spatie\Permission\Exceptions\RoleDoesNotExist::named("super-admin")
      .\vendor\spatie\laravel-permission\src\Models\Role.php:91

  2   Spatie\Permission\Models\Role::findByName("super-admin", "backpack")
      .\vendor\spatie\laravel-permission\src\Traits\HasRoles.php:270
```

what is my options? Why I can't just seed normally with default configuration?

please don't say that I need to manually "seed" the dummy data using Users interface..

Comment: The package caches roles and permissions. Try flushing the cache, and seed again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue caused by Spatie/Laravel-permission also stores model type in the db and puts the permission on the BackpackUser or User model.

Well.. just recently got answer from here:

https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/PermissionManager/issues/193]

the solution is just added on end of 2019 from tabacitu:

https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.0/base-about#having-both-regular-users-and-admins

basically you need either to add middleware, either add is_admin column on User or use the middleware provided by tabacitu

Answer (score 1):

When you are creating your Roles and Permissions, you should define backpack guard using `backpack_guard_name()`:

```
Permission::create([
    'name' => 'view members',
    'guard_name' => backpack_guard_name()
]);
```

Do the same for Roles:

```
Role::create([
    'name' => 'super-admin',
    'guard_name' => backpack_guard_name()
]);
```

On your table, `model_has_roles` your model type can't be `App\User`, it should be `Backpack\Base\app\Models\BackpackUser`:

```
use \Backpack\Base\app\Models\BackpackUser;
...

public function run()
{
    factory(BackpackUser::class)->create([
        'name' => 'Arianna',
        'email' => 'arianna@example.com'
    ])->assignRole('super-admin');
}
```

---

*Note:*

`BackpackUser` extends `App\User`, this may cause you problems because your `User` may have custom fields, and by using `BackpackUser` you don't have those when creating it on a factory.

To solve this, you'd need to do it in two steps. First, creating the `App\User` with all the required fields, then, get the User as a `BackpackUser` object to assign the roles or permissions.

Comment: Hello Antonio, thanks for your answer, if I use the included Laravel Backpack Permission Interface sidebar, the created role will have 'web' as it's default guard name.

So if I seed with 'guard_name' => backpack_guard_name() , the seeded role and permissions will be different from the role and permissions made inserted from the interface